# OSX php homebrew

Tags: php, bash, macos, nginx, terminal

I have been using Mamp/Ampps for a while and decided to remove it and stick with the build in OSX tools and nginx instead. But now (which give sense), When I type "php --version" in the terminal, It gives me the old Mamp Url like so:

```
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

How do I revert this to standard in Macos?
I have tried to simply install a new php version via homebrew, but the above stil occur. I have also tried editing and removing the original mamp line in ~/.bash_profile but no luck.

Comment: Seems like restarting Macos helped.

Comment: Hey simon. From what I can tell, you just needed to `source` your `~./bash_profile` after editing the file so your shell could have the updated `$PATH` variable values. You didn't really need to restart your Mac. But hey, a good old restart solves many problems most of the times!